# MacOS Swift Xcode NSTextField! convert integerValue to doubleValue

Tags: swift, int, double, nstextfield

I would like to have a user input numbers and then have a calculation as the result. I have succeeded with this but I would like the user to be able to input doubles if they want too and also have the result be a double. This is my issue. I have an input TextField box and a Label result. So two Outlets. So the code I have pasted below works but only for whole numbers (ints) Hope this makes sense. Any ideas? Keep in mind I am a newbie to Swift Programming. cheers

using Xcode:

```
@IBOutlet weak var userInput: NSTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var result: NSTextField!
var value = 100

@IBAction func pushButtonforResult(_ sender: Any) {

    result.integerValue = value / userInput.integerValue

}
```

Comment: how about `result.doubleValue` and `userInput.doubleValue`

Comment: and `var value = 100.0`

Comment: value is an integer.  userInput.integerValue is an integer.  An integer / an integer will produce a double value?

Comment: I have seen many topics like this one.  I vote to close it.

Comment: Hey thanks. I already had tried result.doubleValue and userInput.doubleValue but it was giving me an error.  The issue which is now solved thanks to you is this: var value = 100.0   What I was doing was this:  var value = Double (100)   I realize that there are many topics about converting integers to doubles but I could not find anything that solved my issue. None gave the simple answer that you wrote. So very appreciated. I will remove this topic if you think I should. Thanks again!